# @media query does not seem to be working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Does anyone know or could point me in the right direction with this site, I have major issues with IE 11. I have not tested lower than this yet but Chroms, FF, Safari all work fine.

If you compare this website in both you will see the difference, it looks to me like media queries are not applying to the website. But I have no idea how to get it working. I know this is a glow in the dark!

[www.stamford.ac.uk](http://www.stamford.ac.uk)

Comment: Looks fine for me except "find a course" isn't responsive.

Comment: Are you serious, could you send me a screen grab please. Im wandering whether an internal network policy on out image is affecting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left side is Chrome and right side is IE11. I don't see any differences, but the menu needs more contrast and the "Find a Course" needs adjustment to be responsive.

[image: Left side is Chrome and right side is IE11]

[image: Left side is Chrome and right side is IE11]

Comment: Can you please take screen grabs of images with the browser wider than 1000px please to see the full width layout.

Comment: Updated the answer to show large. IE's menu does shift up and to the right like in Chrome when it's resized just a hair bigger.

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems to be an internal problem rolled out via our Group Poliucy! :) Bloody Network Architects :) Haha, good job he sits next to me.

Comment: I can only imagine how long you had been pulling your hair out before posting on SO.

Comment: HOURS!!! 8AM this morning, I kid you not I was close to walking out and going home! (Steve whys this not working, whys this broken.. haha! - Time to pass the book :) )